# Angular velocity of planets around Earth, and Sun

Tags: orbit, solar-system, orbital-mechanics

What are the values of angular velocity of planets around Earth, and Sun? I am looking for these two sets of values.

Comment: While JamesK already provided a very good answer: what is your own though and motivation the actual problem? No offence meant, but as is in this brevity, the question reads a bit unmotivated to just do the conversion from revolution period to angular velocity yourself. Why is this more interesting than putting the numbers into the calculator?

Answer (score 2):

These are not constant.  For the angular velocity around the sun, the planets move at different angular velocities at different times.  Their angular velocity increases when they are close to the sun, in accordance with Kepler's second law.

But the average angular velocity can be calculated: $\omega= 2\pi/T$, where $T$ is the period of revolution in seconds.

| Planet | Period of Revolution (days) | Angular velocity (rad s<sup>-1</sup>) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mercury | 88 | 8.264E-07 |
| Venus | 225 | 3.232E-07 |
| Earth | 365 | 1.992E-07 |
| Mars | 687 | 1.059E-07 |
| Jupiter | 4346 | 1.673E-08 |
| Saturn | 7825 | 9.294E-09 |
| Uranus | 30681 | 2.370E-09 |
| Neptune | 60193 | 1.208E-09 |

The angular velocity is given in radians per second.

For the angular velocity around the Earth, this is even less constant. It would make no sense to quote any figure, even an average or an approximation. Instead you need to [generate an ephemeris](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.htm).  At the moment, the ephemeris generated for Mars gives it a sky motion (angular velocity around the Earth) of 1.8876457 arcseconds per minute or 1.52E-07 radians per second.